# Best approach to send updates to other micro services which are running(multiple instances) in different data centers

Tags: microservices, production-environment, multiple-instances

I have 3 different micro services(ex: A,B,C. these are REST, and springboot based). These 3 different services generally runs on 3 different data centers locations, so i.e different instances for each service.

The problem trying to solve:
I need to send updates(its kind of polling, checking if there are any updated records) in service A, then send updated information to services B and C, through REST call. Based on these updates service B and C does it's own processing. Once after deployment(mostly into cloud). How does A knows which B, C instances are up and running. SO that it can send updates to running instances.

Do we need to keep track of running instances into some DB table and lookup for active instances before sending updates from A?. (OR) just create some indicator or sequence number based approach to find out there are some updates at A, So we need to send out.But in this does it A knows what all are active instances running? Or else, we just need to send updates from A, so that some router or load balancer or some other thing will takes care of sending to available active instances running regardless of storing and looking up for active instances

I am not much familiar with network and prod systems behavior and its communication in cloud systems.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to implement cross service update through REST based synchronization is a bad idea because it is not scalable in a sense that if you add more microservices that needs to be aware of updates made on service A. You would have to modify the existing microservice that emits the change. This in fact introduces risk and additional maintenance cost.

However, you can try to use [messaging queues](https://wiredcraft.com/blog/building-microservices-nsq-rabbitmq/) to emit events that indicates changes made on a service. This approach eliminates the need to modify any existing microservice (Thanks to pub/sub pattern) and just plug new consumers to your existing update emitting services in your ecosystem